# Different versions of a package are requierd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, expo

I'm trying to install Expo, React and React-Native as dependencies of a project. The `package.jason` is like this:

```
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^28.0.0",
    "expo-three": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "react-native": "0.48.3",
    "react": "15.0.0",
    "three": "^0.93.0"
}
```

The problem is that each package needs a specific version for dep and peer dep!. By installing a particular version of a package, others throw error.

```
├── expo@28.0.0
├── expo-three@3.0.0-alpha.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.0.0
├── react-native@0.48.3
└── three@0.93.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@> 15.0.0, required by react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^16.0, required by react-native-maps@0.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@16.0.0-alpha.6, required by react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.3
```

I thought that I can install the latest version and support all, but didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried installing `npm i -S react@latest` and seeing what that gives you?

Comment: @Tholle Yes, I have tried. It fixes some errors and makes some new errors! i.e: npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@16.3.1, required by react-native@0.55.4
(while the latest version of react 16.4.1 is installed)

Comment: I see. That's frustrating. Have you tried setting it explicitly to `npm i -S react@16.3.1`?

Comment: @Tholle Yes. The problem is I don't have a good understanding of peer dependencies. I've read this article but couldn't implement. (https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)

Comment: @Saeid, did you ever figure this out? I am running into similar issues with `expo`, `react`, and `react-native`.

Comment: @JohnCraft I came up with a temporary solution. I changed the required version of react in all dependencies, manually! for example, I have react 16.0.0 and react-native-gesture-handler needs react 15.0.0, so I changed it's required version to 16.0.0!

Answer (score 0):

I created a project with a package.json containing only the packages you shared and I installed these packages using `npm` version `6.1.0`

Here's the output:
[image]

This means that you should install versions newer than the ones you have in your package.json

For instance, the `"react-native": "0.48.3",` [requires the react version 16](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13291) and you are using the version 15.

If you update to `"react": "16.3.0"` and `"react-native": "0.54.0"` most of this issues can be solved. However, make sure that you can do this update, there are some caveats when updating React from 15 to 16.

Comment: @helder-robaloelder I appreciate it. But it throws an error like this: │ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0-alpha.6
Looks like that the error is because of hard-coding a specific version. What I have done to fix it (correct or not) was manipulating the package.jason of each package to set the required version to a same or higher number but similar to other packages. For now, it seems working :|